# Can connect with ping but not curl

Tags: curl, ping

I am testing connecting to a remote server from my local machine. Using ping I can successfully connect but if I try with curl it just hangs:

**Working with ping:**

```
$ ping db-machine-02
Pinging db-machine-02.comp.org [xxx.xx.x.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xx.x.xxx: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=51
Reply from xxx.xx.x.xxx: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=51
Reply from xxx.xx.x.xxx: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=51
Reply from xxx.xx.x.xxx: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for xxx.xx.x.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 12ms, Maximum = 12ms, Average = 12ms
```

**Fails/timeout with curl:**

```
$ curl -v db-machine-02
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600077108; line 1332 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x600077108; line 1373 (connection #0)
*   Trying xxx.xx.x.xxx:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600077108; line 1452 (connection #0)
* Connection timed out after 300181 milliseconds
* multi_done
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 300181 milliseconds
```

Why can I connect with `ping` command but not with `curl` command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This could be caused by port 80 on the remote machine being closed. 
Check your firewall rules to ensure this port is open.

Ping does not connect to a port (it uses ICMP), so that is why pinging works without opened ports.

On a side note, your ping and curl commands show you're trying to connect to "db-machine-02". Be aware that databases do not commonly communicate over port 80 by default.

Comment: Ok so its not possible to test connections with curl without specifying port?

Comment: That's right. If you do not specify a port or protocol, curl tries to establish an HTTP connection to port 80 by default. As you can see in the output of your curl command.

Answer (score 2):

If using a proxy server, you may run into trouble if the proxy server cannot 'see' the destination host. For example, if using a test or development environment and your linux development host is configured to use the corporate proxy, then you may need to configure or override the `no_proxy` environment variable.

For example:  Overriding `no_proxy` enables `curl` to work when accessing a local VM webserver from a local VM dev box (and `http_proxy` was set to the corporate proxy). In linux, one option is to override `no_proxy` as you issue the `curl` command:

```
joe@vm-dev-host:~$ no_proxy="192.168.1.123" curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.123/somedata"
```